# Why is the ray client-server not starting?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, azure, ray

I have a script where the workload of some `@ray.remote`-functions should be computed in the cloud. Therefore, I have deployed a ray cluster to azure with the "*Deploy to Azure*" button. Once the head node started, I like to connect the script which is running on my local windows machine to this head node running in azure with

```
import ray
ray.init("ray://<headnodeip>:10001")
```

As far as a I understand the head node should expose port 10001 which can be called from my local script either through port forwarding or through exposing port 10001 to the internet [as per this document](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/cluster/ray-client.html).

To troubleshoot I have stopped and started ray on the head node manually with the following command

```
ray start --head --port=6379 --object-manager-port=8076 --num-gpus=2 --dashboard-host=0.0.0.0 --include-dashboard=true --dashboard-port=8265 --log-style=pretty --verbose --ray-client-server-port=10001
```

The client-server seems to be starting well as per the logs

> INFO server.py:843 -- Starting Ray Client server on 0.0.0.0:10001

But unfortunately my client cannot connect to the cluster (Timeout). I observed the following:

- Tcp connection from local windows machine to cluster via 10001 not possible
- `ss | grep 10001` not showing any results on head node
- Connection to the dashboard is working fine

I now have the following questions:

1. How to check if the client-server is started correctly?
2. Shouldn't the port 10001 be visible in `ss` if the head node is started?
3. What can I further check to resolve the issue?

---

### UPDATE

The `ray start`-command shows the message

> To connect to this Ray runtime from outside of the cluster, for
> example to connect to a remote cluster from your laptop directly,
> use the following Python code:

```
import ray
ray.init(address='ray://<head_node_ip_address>:10001')
```

**I do not understand why I am not seeing any process listening on port 10001 (tested with ss)?**

Comment: In the documentation you linked, did you follow "Step 2: check ports"? As a workaround, you can run `ray attach cluster.yaml -p 10001` to port-forward the remote Ray server to localhost.

Comment: @cade Yes, I have checked the ports and cannot find one listening on 10001. Please see my update.